# Is it possible to check inside beforeSave method if Parse master key is used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

It is important in my app to have no duplicates so I have this code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Thing", function(request, response) {
    var newEntryThing = request.object;
    var thingId= newEntryThing.get("thingId");
    var queryThings= new Parse.Query("Thing");
    queryThings.equalTo("thingId", thingId);

    queryThings.first({
        success: function(results) {
            if(results) {
                response.error({errorCode:400,errorMsg:"Thing already exist"});
            } else {
                response.success();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.success();
        }
    });
});
```

So far this works for that purpose, the problem is that even Parse dashboard cannot update this class anymore, due to the logic. What I am thinking is to check first if the method is called using masterkey if yes, then this logic will be bypassed and would allow update. **Is it possible to check in this beforeSave method if Parse master key is used?**

Comment: "Parse dashboard cannon update this class anymore, due to the logic" ... do you mean that when you try to add a row with a duplicate thingId, that this logic prevents it?  That's what it's supposed to do, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check inside beforeSave() if maskerkey is used (or if you are making the request from the dashboard) try to add this condition in your cloud code :

```
if (request.master){
    . . .//dosomething
}
```